# Using $this from within a function

Tags: php, oop

I have a document that is able to use `$this` to access certain bits of info. Inside that document there is a function which cannot access `$this` (gives an error about not being inside an object).

Is there any way to allow it access to `$this`, so I can run the class's methods from within the function?

I have tried using globals but to no avail.

Comment: Pass it to the function as an argument.

Comment: Of course, no idea why I didn't realise. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the function is defined outside the class, you can pass in an instance of the object and use that.

For example:

```
class A
{
    public function B()
    {
        echo "C";
    }
}

function D($obj)
{
    echo $obj->B();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect. Should have realised that myself though. (Late night, I suppose!)

Comment: Will do.. but I have to wait a few minutes apparently :)

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the function so that it expects an additional parameter. Pass `$this` as argument to that function

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the function is part of the class that you are trying to get a property of use `self` where you would have used this.